# Checking Two lists for circle overlap

Tags: python, geometry, overlap

My goal for this code is to place two size circles based on user input to create a nonoverlapping display of randomly placed circles. As of right now I can place the big circles just fine. The basics of the code is to split it up into grid spaces and check the surrounding grid spaces for circles and then check for overlap.
With my smaller circles, I want to check the list that holds the smaller circles and if there is no overlap, check that with the list of bigger circles again with the grid idea. My code right now does not put any circles into the smaller circle list so in a result does not print out any onto the grid.

```
#Small grid information
sgrid_minw = 6*smallradius
sgrid_minh = 6*smallradius

n_smgridX = math.floor(1/sgrid_minw)
n_smgridY = math.floor(1/sgrid_minh)

actualsmgrid_w = 1/n_smgridX
actualsmgrid_h = 1/n_smgridY

v_smcircle = [[ [] for _ in range (n_smgridX)] for _ in range(n_smgridY)]
print(v_smcircle)
n_addsmall = 1
small_circles = 0
while n_addsmall > 0:

n_addsmall = 0
for _ in range(1000):
  smallr = smallradius
  x = random.uniform(smallr, 1-smallr)
  y = random.uniform(smallr, 1-smallr)
  c_candidate = Circle(x, y, smallr)

  grid_i = math.floor(x/actualgrid_w)
  grid_j = math.floor(y/actualgrid_h)

  grid_smi = math.floor(x/actualsmgrid_w)
  grid_smj = math.floor(x/actualsmgrid_h)

  #print("Candidate circle pos and grid : ("+str(x)+", "+str(y)+",["+str(grid_smi)+", "+str(grid_smj)+"]")

  small_check = False
  for i in range(max(0, grid_smi-1), min(grid_smi+2, n_smgridX)):
    for j in range(max(0, grid_smj-1), min(grid_smj+2, n_smgridY)):
      if len(v_smcircle[i][j]) > 0:
        for c_iteration in v_smcircle[i][j]:
          if distance(c_candidate, c_iteration) < c_iteration.radius_ + c_candidate.radius_:
            small_check = True
  big_check = False
  if not small_check:
    for i in range(max(0, grid_i-1), min(grid_i+2, n_gridX)):
      for j in range(max(0, grid_j-1), min(grid_j+2, n_gridY)):
        if len(v_circle[i][j]) > 0:
          for big_circle in v_circle[i][j]:
            if distance(big_circle, c_candidate) >= big_circle.radius_ + c_candidate.radius_:
              big_check = True
  if not big_check:
    v_smcircle[grid_smi][grid_smj].append(c_candidate)
    n_addsmall = n_addsmall + 1
    small_circles += 1
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing the grid.  Determining whether a circle overlaps any other circle is easy -- you have the code there -- but that doesn't involve grids at all.